# Remove moving objects to get the background model from multiple images

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to find the background in multiple images captured with a fixed camera. Camera detect moving objects(animal) and captured sequential Images. So I need to find a simple background model image by process 5 to 10 captured images with same background.

Can someone help me please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your eventual goal to find foreground? Can you show some images?

If animals move fast enough they will create a lot of intensity changes while background pixels will remain closely correlated among most of the frames. I won’t write you real code but will give you a pseudo-code in openCV. The main idea is to average only correlated pixels:

```
Mat Iseq[10];// your sequence
Mat result, Iacc=0, Icnt=0; // Iacc and Icnt are float types
loop through your sequence, i=0; i<N-1; i++
   matchTemplate(Iseg[i], Iseq[i+1], result, CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
   mask = 1 & (result>0.9); // get correlated part, which is probably background
   Iacc += Iseq[i] & mask + Iseq[i+1] & mask; // accumulate background infer
   Icnt += 2*mask; // keep count
end of loop;
Mat Ibackground = Iacc.mul(1.0/Icnt); // average background (moving parts fade away)
```

To improve the result you may reduce mage resolution or apply blur to enhance correlation. You can also clean every mask from small connected components by erosion, for example.

Comment: Yes I want to find the foreground objects by applying Frame Difference method, for this I need a simple background image but my camera only take picture when a motion is detected. Another issue is the background is changing with duration of time(after 10 or 20 captured) so i need to find BG at runtime.
You can see Images here.
[link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/30794/remove-moving-objects-to-get-the-background-from/)

Comment: Looking at your images I would try converting them in Lab space to get rid of lighting variations even better switching to gradient of grey. Running motion detector will help to find station background. Note that instead of motion you can simply detect the absence of it by running matchTemplate in several parts of the image. Quadtree may partition the image even better. I believe Maltab has a nice sample with quadtree

Comment: Yes its amazing and I think it will work fine for me. I am not so much aware of Matlab usage but let me try. Thanks @Vlad

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 5 images it's going to be hard to identify background and most sophisticated techniques probably won't work. For general background identification methods, see [Link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/280225)

Answer (score 0):

If

- each pixel location appears as background in more than half the frames, and
- the colour of a pixel does not vary much across the subset of frames in which it is background,

then there's a very simple algorithm: for each pixel location, **just take the median intensity over all frames**.

How come? Suppose the image is greyscale (this makes it easier to explain, but the process will work for colour images too -- just treat each colour component separately).  If a particular pixel appears as background in more than half the frames, then when you take the intensities of that pixel across all frames and sort them, a background-coloured pixel must appear at the half-way (median) position.  (In the worst case, all background-coloured pixels get pushed to the very front or the very back in this order, but even then there are enough of them to cover the half-way point.)

Comment: great idea but can suffer from lighting or exposure changes.

Comment: @Vlad: True, but the question says "same background".  If those kinds of changes are allowed then the question becomes much harder.

Comment: It is rarely the case if not a misspoke statement that their is a  same background in real life problems. In fact, his saying that camera is motion activated and motion comes from animals indicates that lighting changes, noise and autoexposure changes are there. This being said, some methods can be adjusted for that while others cannot and it is reasonable to start simple.